# Proving $f_{s}(t) = \frac{e^{-st}}{t}$ is uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I am new to proving uniform convergence and am trying to show that $$f_{s}(t) = \frac{e^{-st}}{t}$$ is uniformly convergent $\forall$ $s\geq 0$. I am pretty sure that $t\epsilon \mathbb{R}$. I first thought of taking the derivative of the function to find the maximum since t is in an open set, but I remember that since I am showing that $\left |f_{s}(t)\right |<\varepsilon$, and knowing that the value of $f_{s}(t)$ when $t<0$ (the value of the local maximum of $f_{s}(t)$ is also less than $0$) is negative, if one were to take the absolute value, then the local maximum would become a local minimum. Also, there would not be a maximum, since $\lim _{s\rightarrow0} \rightarrow+\infty$. I know that the answer to this question is that $f_{s}(t)$ is uniformly convergent to $0$ as $t\rightarrow+\infty$,$\forall$ $s\geq 0$, but I am stuck at the point where I am at right now. Is there any theorem or something that I can use to help me with my proof?

Edit: This is in the context to use the Dirichlet test to show that an integrand composed of a product is uniformly convergent, so taking that in mind, should it be restricted to only the positive real numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For uniform convergence as $t \to +\infty$ you can consider the behavior when $t$ is positive.  For all $s \geqslant 0$ we have

$$0 < \frac{e^{-st}}{t} \leqslant \frac{1}{t}$$

and it is now easy to conclude that convergence is uniform.

Comment: Thank you I have not thought of that! It seems so obvious now but again I'm new to this material.

Comment: @Eliot: You're welcome.

Comment: Actually isn't the relationship supposed to be independent of t? So wouldn't this prove point-wise convergence and not uniform convergence?

Comment: Here we are showing uniform convergence to $0$ as $t \to \infty$ for all values of the parameter $s \geqslant 0$. It's uniform because $|f_s(t) - 0| < 1/t < \epsilon$ for $t > T(\epsilon) = 1/\epsilon$ and $T(\epsilon)$ does not depend on $s$.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thank you again.